# listbox with image tap

Tags: c#, xaml, telerik, windows-phone

How to achieve this ui?

item1 | X
item2 | X
item3 | X

with item1,item2,item3 have SelectionChanged event and X is an image with tap event

I tried this

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox
    x:Name="AddressListBox"
    ItemsSource="{Binding hereRestAddressDetail}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding hereRestDetail}"
    SelectionChanged="AddressListBox_SelectionChanged" 
    ItemAnimationMode="PlayAll"
    EmptyContent="">
    <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="10">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.by, 
                                            Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" 
                                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding creator}" Margin="-8,0,0,0"
                                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding street}"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding formatedStreet}" 
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding ratingButton}" Grid.Column="2" 
                       Stretch="Uniform" Width="80"
                       Tag="{Binding Id}" Tap="rate_Tap"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ratingValue}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"
                           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>

</telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox>
```

but when I tap into image it will execute my event (in this condition I just testing it with showing messagebox ) but after that it also executing my SelectionChanged event...

how to specify that only image tap event that triggered when I tap into the image?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
bool ignoreSelectionChanged;
void rate_Tap(...) {
    ignoreSelectionChanged = true;
    //do you image tap things here
}
void AddressListBox_SelectionChanged(...) {
    if(ignoreSelectionChanged) {
        ignoreSelectionChanged = false; //reset the bool, so that it will skip only once
        return;
    }
    //do your things on selection change here
}
```